# Web3 Uniswap/Pancake Retrive last swap transacion contract BUY/SELL

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I made a simple python script that reads me the real-time price of the coins using Web3 and the ABI getAmountsOut function.

```
router = w3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(pancakeSwapADDRESS), abi=PancakeABI)
amountIn = w3.toWei(tokenToSell, 'ether')
```

Everything works correctly but now I would like to add to the script the possibility to see the last transactions of the contract if in BUY or SELL.

I am trying this method but I cannot distinguish the SWAP and IF value in BUY and SELL.

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=adr_chk, abi=PancakeABI)
transfer_filter = contract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock="latest")
t = transfer_filter.get_new_entries()
```

How could I solve?